# How to remove '_' from the output in python code?

Tags: python

I have written one python code in which final output is coming with '_' symbol. So i want to remove this symbol.

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

file = ["meta_data_02154.csv", "meta_data_021694.csv", "meta_data_loop_02365.csv", "meta_data_loops_0256365.csv", "output.csv"]

f = [list(i) for j, i in groupby(file, lambda a : re.split(r'\d*.csv$', a)[0])]
print(f)

for pattern in f:
        #print(pattern)
        print((re.split(r'\d*.csv$', pattern[0]))[0])
```

Output:

```
[['meta_data_02154.csv', 'meta_data_021694.csv'], ['meta_data_loop_02365.csv'], ['meta_data_loops_0256365.csv'], ['output.csv']]
meta_data_
meta_data_loop_
meta_data_loops_
output
```

Desire Output:

```
[['meta_data_02154.csv', 'meta_data_021694.csv'], ['meta_data_loop_02365.csv'], ['meta_data_loops_0256365.csv'], ['output.csv']]
meta_data
meta_data_loop
meta_data_loops
output
```

Comment: use rstrip('_')

Comment: `print((re.split(r'_?\d*.csv$', pattern[0]))[0])`?

Comment: @shivam patel, both your desired and gotten output are the same.

Comment: `print((re.split(r'\d*.csv$', pattern[0]))[0].rstrip('_'))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use **[rstrip()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rstrip.html)**

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

file = ["meta_data_02154.csv", "meta_data_021694.csv", "meta_data_loop_02365.csv", "meta_data_loops_0256365.csv", "output.csv"]

f = [list(i) for j, i in groupby(file, lambda a : re.split(r'\d*.csv$', a)[0])]
print(f)

for pattern in f:
        #print(pattern)
        print((re.split(r'\d*.csv$', pattern[0]))[0].rstrip('_'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `rstrip()`

```
val = "sad_"
print(val.rstrip('_'))
Output: sad
```

> **Description**
>
> `rstip()` Returns a copy of the string with right trailing
>   characters removed.

Alternatively
`print(val[:-1])` will give same result in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Try pattern `r'_?\d*.csv$'`.

**Ex:**

```
import re
from itertools import groupby

file = ["meta_data_02154.csv", "meta_data_021694.csv", "meta_data_loop_02365.csv", "meta_data_loops_0256365.csv", "output.csv"]

f = [list(i) for j, i in groupby(file, lambda a : re.split(r'\d*.csv$', a)[0])]
print(f)

for pattern in f:
    #print(pattern)
    print((re.split(r'_?\d*.csv$', pattern[0]))[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `print((re.split(r'\d*.csv$', pattern[0]))[0].rstrip('_')` but you might as well use a better regex and `.search` instead of `split`.

I'm not sure what you used `groupby` for.

```
import re

file = ["meta_data_02154.csv", "meta_data_021694.csv", "meta_data_loop_02365.csv", "meta_data_loops_0256365.csv", "output.csv"]

for pattern in file:
    print(re.search(r'(.+)\d*.csv$', pattern).group(1))
```

Outputs

```
meta_data_02154
meta_data_021694
meta_data_loop_02365
meta_data_loops_0256365
output
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a one-liner, just splitting the filenames:

```
file = ["meta_data_02154.csv", "meta_data_021694.csv", "meta_data_loop_02365.csv", "meta_data_loops_0256365.csv", "output.csv"]
filePatterns = set([f.rsplit('_', 1)[0].rsplit('.csv')[0] for f in file])
print(filePatterns)
```

Prints:

```
{'meta_data_loops', 'meta_data', 'meta_data_loop', 'output'}
```